# itextsharp / MCV combining multiple forms into one PDF using bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

Hi My applion is MVC3 c#, I am using itextsharp to produce PDF files for pre disgned forms.  In this application I have to different forms.  To generate a form I use:

```
public ActionResult TestPDF(long learnerID = 211, long courseID = 11)
{
    var caseList = _studyCaseSvc.ListStudyCases().Where(x => x.Course_ID == courseID);
    try
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfConcatenate whole = new PdfConcatenate(memoryStream);
        foreach (var ca in caseList)
        {
            byte[] part = null;
            if (ca.CaseType == "CTA")
            {
                part = GenerateEvaluationCAT_PDF(learnerID, ca.ID);
            }
            else if (ca.CaseType == "CTAH")
            {
                part = GenerateEvaluationCATH_PDF(learnerID, ca.ID);
            }
            else
            {
                part = null;
            }
            if (part != null)
            {
                PdfReader partReader = new PdfReader(part);
                whole.AddPages(partReader);
                partReader.Close();
            }
        }

        whole.Close();
        byte[] byteInfo = memoryStream.ToArray();
        SendPdfToBrowser(byteInfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get this error: An item with the same key has already been added.  The error happens at AddPages.  So I developed this simpler test:

```
private void merge()
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream output = new FileStream("p3.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            PdfConcatenate pdfConcatenate = new PdfConcatenate(output, true);

            PdfReader r1 = new PdfReader("p2.pdf");

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(r1, memoryStream);

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();
            PdfReader r2 = new PdfReader(memoryStream.ToArray());

            //pdfConcatenate.AddPages(tempReader);

            pdfConcatenate.Open();
            int n = r1.NumberOfPages;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage imp = pdfConcatenate.Writer.GetImportedPage(r1, i);
                pdfConcatenate.Writer.AddPage(imp);
            }
            pdfConcatenate.Writer.FreeReader(r1);

            pdfStamper.Close();
            r1.Close();
            pdfConcatenate.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is the misconception that you can combine multiple PDF files into one by simply concatenating them.  That is wrong for PDFs (just like it is wrong for most binary file formats).

Thus,  you should update your GenerateAllEvaluation_PDF method to have a  PdfConcatenate instance instead of your byte Array whole, cf. http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfConcatenate.html, open each byte array returned by your GenerateEvaluationCATH_PDF method in a PdfReader, add all pages of these readers to the PdfConcatenate and eventually return the bytes generated by that class.

**EDIT** (I'm more into Java than C#, thus forgive minor errors)

```
PdfConcatenate whole = new PdfConcatenate(...);
foreach (var ca in caseList)
{
    byte[] part = null;
    if (ca.CaseType == "CTA")
    {
        part = GenerateEvaluationCAT_PDF(learnerID, ca.ID);
    }
    else if (ca.CaseType == "CTAH")
    {
        part = GenerateEvaluationCATH_PDF(learnerID, ca.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        part = ???;
    }
    PdfReader partReader = new PdfReader(part);
    whole.AddPages(partReader);
    partReader.Close();
}
```

The PdfConcatenate can be constructed with a MemoryStream from which you can retrieve the final byte[].

**PS**: `PdfConcatenate` may not be a part of iTextSharp version 4.x yet but it is merely a convenience wrapper of PdfCopy and PdfSmartCopy. Thus, you may simply have a look at the sources of iTextSharp (OSS after all) and be inspired: [PdfConcatenate.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/455/tree/tags/iTextSharp_5_3_3/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfConcatenate.cs).

Comment: Thanks mkl, since I am not that exprienced, I would really appreciate if you assist me by providing more details on how I can implement your suggestion.  Regards

Comment: Thank you mkl, unfortunately PdfConcatenate is not part of itextshparp.

Comment: It is part of iTextSharp, but maybe only of the 5.x versions. It is merely a convenience wrapper of PdfCopy and PdfSmartCopy. Thus, you may simply have a look at the sources of iTextSharp (OSS after all) and be inspired.

Comment: Thanks mkl, I got this error An item with the same key has already been added, when I use itextsharp PdfConcatenate.Addpages.

Comment: Please update your question to contain a runnable version of your current code, so we know exactly what we talk about.

Comment: Done, I have uppdated the question.  Thank you so much for your help so far.

Comment: Ok, could you also supply the document `p2.pdf` to allow for an identical test run here?

Comment: Ah, I just read on the itext-questions mailing list: [iText-Sharp - PDFCopy.GetImportedPage](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iText-Sharp-PDFCopy-GetImportedPage-tt4656983.html#a4656984) --- so maybe you deal with a genuine iTextSharp bug which is in the process of being fixed.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the bug, I added the itextsharp core library to my simple project to debug it, the error was was in the GetImportedPage.  I did also change P2.PDF to other files, it is the same.  Would you suggest to wait for the fix to try an alternative approach?  Thanks again for your support

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19836/discussion-between-user373721-and-mkl)

Comment: @user373721 The bug seems to be fixed in the SVN repository, cf. [PDF concatenate errors in version 5.3.4](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PDF-concatenate-errors-in-version-5-3-4-tp4657034p4657035.html) on the iText-questions mailing list. Version 5.3.5 should, therefore, work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much mkl, I also found this solution http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger, and it is working now. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. Be aware, though, that that solution drops all interactive features of the original PDFs, e.g. interactive forms.